# How to perform reverse relation in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

This is my models:

```
class Journal(models.Model):
    Start_Date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date(2018,4,1),blank=False)
    End_Date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date(2019,3,31),blank=False)
    Date = models.DateField()
    By = models.ForeignKey(ledger1,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='Debitledgers')
    To = models.ForeignKey(ledger1,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='Creditledgers')
    Debit = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)
    Credit = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)
```

I want to filter the journal objects within the "Start_Date" and "End_Date" of the journal model...

I mean to say The "Date" in journal must be between the "Start_Date" and "End_Date" of journal...

This might me a stupid question to ask...But, as I am learning django, its not easy for me...

Can anyone tell me how to do this???

Thank you in advance

Comment: So you have a `Start_date` and/or `End_Date`? What is the input, and what should be the output?

Comment: I won't put an answer because I'm not clear exactly what query you want doing, but try looking at the official documentation (Django has some of the best and most detailed I've seen anywhere!), particularly here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/

Comment: I want to filter all the journal objects which is created within the 'Start_Date'  and the "End_Date" of the selectdate objects

Comment: The "Date" in journal must be between the "Start_Date" and "End_Date" of selectdate

Comment: @NiladryKar: but why do you have a `ForeignKey` to a `Journal` here?

Comment: The `related_name='journals'` is *very* strange, since this is the relation in reverse, so a logical consueqence is to name it `selectiondates`.

Comment: I have updated my code...Can anyone tell me the solution in this case???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use [`F expression`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F) like this:

```
Journal.object.filter(journals__Start_Date__gt=F('Date'), journals__End_Date__lt=F('Date'))
```

Actually it's not clear what exacly `Selectdate` model do. If you create it for filtering purpose only, you can remove it and use ORM without it:

```
Journal.object.filter(Date__gt=some_date_start, Date__lt=some_date_end)
```

As for updated question you can do this:

```
Journal.object.filter(Start_Date__gte=F('Date'), End_Date__lte=F('Date'))
```

Comment: Where does the `journals__` originate from?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem `Journal` field has `related_name='journals'` argument.

Comment: According to my models...How can I put 'Date' present in journal model class in your answer?

Comment: Yeah Its only for filtering purpose

Comment: @NiladryKar I've updated my answer. You need two variables `some_date_start` and `some_date_end`. Based on this variables you can get all journals in this interval using foloowing query: `Journal.object.filter(Date__gt=some_date_start, Date__lt=some_date_end)`

Comment: This thing I know very well, But as a learner I want to know if I can do anything like reverse relationship using foreign key

Comment: @NiladryKar Sorry, probably I didn't understand your question, but yes you can use reverse relations in filter also. Check first part of answer.